# Cutting cylinder form a space

Tags: general-topology, 3d

We have a 3 dimensional space.
At all points of this space a value(density for example) is defined.
This value changes ***smoothly***.

The question is: "Can I always cut a cylinder from this space, so that it's center of mass is on it's main axis?"

By "***smoothly***" there are 2 cases to consider:

1. along any curve, the value "do not jump"
2. first condition holds, moreover the derivative of the value "do not jump" too.

Comment: I am sorry for bad English and knowledge mathematical terms. I described problem as clear as I could. I don't even know what part of math is related to this. I would be grateful if you corrected me too!

Comment: While I don't have a complete argument, I am highly confident that the answer is yes. If you were asking a shape in the plane with center-symmetry and some axis through it, then I could say it absolutely: Draw it anywhere. The COM (center of mass) will lie on one side or the other of the axis. Rotate the shape $180^\circ$. By symmetry, the COM is in the same spot, but this is the other side of the axis now. As everything is continuous, at some point in the rotation, the COM crossed the axis.

Comment: But in 3D, it is more complicated. A similar argument shows that the COM lies on a plane through the axis. And you could then try another rotation taking that plane to itself to get the axis to pass through the COM, that rotation of the cylinder may result in the COM leaving the plane, ruining the idea. A full proof will require a more topological argument, similar to what is sometimes used to prove the Borsuk-Ulam theorem.